# Character detection in a text file in Python using the Universal Encoding Detector (chardet)

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am trying to use the Universal Encoding Detector (chardet) in Python to detect the most probable character encoding in a text file ('infile') and use that in further processing.

While chardet is designed primarily for detecting the character encoding of webpages, I have found an [example](http://dbaktiar.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/chardet-python-library-determining-character-encoding-of-text/) of it being used on individual text files.

However, I cannot work out how to tell the script to set the most likely character encoding to the variable 'charenc' (which is used several times throughout the script).

My code, based on a combination of the aforementioned example and chardet's own [documentation](http://chardet.feedparser.org/docs/usage.html) is as follows:

```
import chardet    
rawdata=open(infile,"r").read()
chardet.detect(rawdata)
```

Character detection is necessary as the script goes on to run the following (as well as several similar uses):

```
inF=open(infile,"rb")
s=unicode(inF.read(),charenc)
inF.close()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`chardet.detect()` returns a dictionary which provides the encoding as the value associated with the key `'encoding'`. So you can do this:

```
import chardet    
rawdata = open(infile, 'rb').read()
result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
charenc = result['encoding']
```

[The `chardet` documentation](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is not explicitly clear about whether text strings and/or byte strings are supposed to work with the module, but it stands to reason that if you have a text string you don't need to run character detection on it, so you should probably be passing byte strings. Hence the binary mode flag (`b`) in the call to `open()`. But `chardet.detect()` might also work with a text string depending on which versions of Python and of the library you're using, i.e. if you do omit the `b` you might find that it works anyway even though you're technically doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would be something simple!

Comment: Just what I needed. Out of curiosity, is there some way to get it to return more than one result so you can see say, the 3 highest confidence level guesses?

Comment: @Endophage I'm not sure, I haven't really used it much myself.

Comment: Python 3.6 threw ```TypeError: Expected object of type bytes or bytearray, got: <class 'str'>``` when attempting to open a UTF-8 file.
Opening with ```"rb"``` instead of ```"r"``` fixed the problem.

Comment: @JohnLemberger Ah good point, I've fixed that. I believe it worked in the past when Python wasn't so picky about the distinction between text strings and byte strings.

Comment: There is an alternative to chardet. If you are not happy with it. charset-normalizer https://github.com/Ousret/charset_normalizer

Comment: This method just hangs my kernel forever.

Comment: @Ousret also available at https://pypi.org/project/charset-normalizer/ which means you can install it with `pip`.  I haven't had a chance to try it yet but it looks interesting.

Comment: what if chardet returns None as the encoding?