# "for line in..." results in UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

Here is my code,

```
for line in open('u.item'):
# Read each line
```

Whenever I run this code it gives the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 2892: invalid continuation byte

I tried to solve this and add an extra parameter in open(). The code looks like:

```
for line in open('u.item', encoding='utf-8'):
# Read each line
```

But again it gives the same error. What should I do then?

Comment: Badly encoded data I would assume.

Comment: Or just not UTF-8 data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 UnicodeDecodeError - How do I debug UnicodeDecodeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180610/python-3-unicodedecodeerror-how-do-i-debug-unicodedecodeerror)

Comment: We had this error with msgpack when using python 3 instead of python 2.7. For us, the course of action was to work with python 2.7.

Answer (score 663, accepted):

As [suggested by Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/for-line-in-results-in-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte/19699399#19699399), I found the right encoding for that problem. The encoding was [`"ISO-8859-1"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), so replacing `open("u.item", encoding="utf-8")` with `open('u.item', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")` will solve the problem.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit (PEP 20).

Comment: The trick is that ISO-8859-1 or Latin_1 is 8 bit character sets, thus all garbage has a valid value. Perhaps not useable, but if you want to ignore!

Comment: I had the same issue UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 32: invalid continuation byte.
I used python 3.6.5 to install aws cli.
And when I tried aws --version it failed with this error.
So I had to edit /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/configparser.py
and changed the code to the following
**def read(self, filenames, encoding="ISO-8859-1"):**

Comment: Is there an automatic way of detecting encoding?

Comment: @OrangeSherbet I implemented detection using `chardet`. Here's the one-liner (after `import chardet`): `chardet.detect(open(in_file, 'rb').read())['encoding']`. Check out this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323810/615422

Comment: How do you get the encoding of a file?

Comment: Note that `'ISO-8859-1'` will *always* work even if it's not the right encoding, because each of the 256 byte values maps to a Unicode character.  I believe it's the only encoding which does this.

Comment: I like @VertigoRay's suggestion of `chardet` in a script, but for something really quick to diagnose what's going on, a simple `file` helped me: `% file list.log 
list.log: ISO-8859 text` vs `%file playlist.txt 
playlist.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF, LF line terminators`

Comment: @vertigoray answer should be the accepted one IMHO -- answers without encoding detection cannot reliably solve the question

Comment: @OrangeSherbet there's no sure way unless you can find out from whoever produced the file.  But it's possible to guess based on the file contents and some guessing methods are better than others.  By coincidence I chanced on a new way to do it in Python the other day: [charset-normalizer](https://pypi.org/project/charset-normalizer/).

Answer (score 91):

The following also worked for me. [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is going to save a lot, mainly if using Speech Recognition APIs.

Example:

```
file = open('../Resources/' + filename, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: You may be correct that the OP is reading ISO 8859-1, as can be deduced from the 0xe9 (é) in the error message, but you should explain why your solution works. The reference to speech recognitions API's does not help.

Answer (score 42):

Your file doesn't actually contain UTF-8 encoded data; it contains some other encoding. Figure out what that encoding is and use it in the `open` call.

In [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding, for example, the `0xe9` would be the character `é`.

Comment: So, How can I find out what encoding is it! I am using linux

Comment: There is no way to do that that always works, but see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file

Answer (score 30):

Try this to read using [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29):

```
pd.read_csv('u.item', sep='|', names=m_cols, encoding='latin-1')
```

Comment: Not sure why you're suggesting Pandas. The solution is setting the correct encoding, which you've chanced upon here.

Comment: 'latin-1' is the same as 'ISO-8859-1'?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes it is, [Wikipedia confirms it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).  They both produce the same output when used with `decode` in Python as well.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack one more late comment, `'latin-1'` will always read a file without error because there are no invalid bytes in that encoding, even if it produces the wrong characters.  It is the only encoding in Python with that property.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm not sure about that :) What's an invalid byte in any 8bit code page? Surely, all the iso-8859 code pages will accept any byte?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack you're right, many of the ISO-8859 variants work with every byte value, even though they generate different characters from those bytes.  But not all of them: iso8859_3 fails with 0xa5, iso8859_6 fails with 0xa1, iso8859_7 fails with 0xae, iso8859_8 fails with 0xa1, and iso8859_11 fails with 0xdb.

Comment: @MarkRansom I admire your dedication and tenacity to science! Thank you. Have a great weekend

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I'd hardly call it dedication and tenacity, you just made me curious.  I'd always assumed that iso8859_1 was the only one that could decode every byte value, so I tried them all; it turns out a lot of them can do it: iso8859_2, iso8859_4, iso8859_5, iso8859_9, iso8859_10, iso8859_13, iso8859_14, iso8859_15, and iso8859_16.  Latin-1 aka iso8859_1 is still unique in having a direct 1:1 correspondence between byte values and Unicode code points.

Answer (score 23):

This works:

```py
open('filename', encoding='latin-1')
```

Or:

```py
open('filename', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "works".  If you mean avoids exceptions that's true, because it's the only encoding that doesn't have invalid bytes or sequences.  Doesn't mean you'll get the proper characters though.

Answer (score 18):

You could resolve the problem with:

```
for line in open(your_file_path, 'rb'):
```

'rb' is reading the file in binary mode. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Python 2, the following will be the solution:

```
import io
for line in io.open("u.item", encoding="ISO-8859-1"):
    # Do something
```

Because the `encoding` parameter doesn't work with `open()`, you will be getting the following error:

> TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: But this is version 3

Comment: Yeah I know. I thought it might be helpful for the people using `Python 2`

Comment: Worked for me in Python3 as well

Comment: In case you want something easier to remember, `'ISO-8859-1'` is also known as `'latin-1'` or `'latin1'`.

Answer (score 9):

I was using a dataset downloaded from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/leonardopena/top50spotify2019) while reading this dataset it threw this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position
> 183: invalid continuation byte

So this is how I fixed it.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('top50.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

Comment: I've tried the below code.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this way:

```
open('u.item', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26211981)

Comment: @MartenCatcher yeah but it helps future visitors to the question, although more explanation put to the answer would make it much better, I believe it serves better purpose as an answer rather than as a comment

Comment: What is the intent? Ignoring errors? What are the consequences?

Comment: it's useful if you don't know the source encoding, and you just want to get a "close enough" string. for example, output of Powershell commands in different OS locales, where you just want to search for a specific language-independent string, you don't actually care what the rest of the text says

Comment: this is not a wise choice to ignore the errors - sometimes they will provide insight to how to improve your code... let alone how to fix the issues you are running into. Otherwise things will fail and you won't know why

Answer (score 6):

Based on [another question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text) and previous answers in this post, I would like to add a help to find the right encoding.

If your script runs on a Linux OS, you can get the encoding with the `file` command:

```
file --mime-encoding <filename>
```

Here is a python script to do that for you:

```py
import sys
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Usage: {} <filename>".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

def find_encoding(fname):
    """Find the encoding of a file using file command
    """

    # find fullname of file command
    which_run = subprocess.run(['which', 'file'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    if which_run.returncode != 0:
        print("Unable to find 'file' command ({})".format(which_run.returncode))
        return None

    file_cmd = which_run.stdout.decode().replace('\n', '')

    # run file command to get MIME encoding
    file_run = subprocess.run([file_cmd, '--mime-encoding', fname],
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if file_run.returncode != 0:
        print(file_run.stderr.decode(), file=sys.stderr)

    # return  encoding name only
    return file_run.stdout.decode().split()[1]

# test
print("Encoding of {}: {}".format(sys.argv[1], find_encoding(sys.argv[1])))
```

Comment: I was looking for an answer and interestingly you've answered 7 hours ago to a question asked 8 years ago. interesting coincidence .

Comment: I don't get it, why would you use a 33-line program to avoid typing one line in the shell?

Comment: Also there are ways to do it within Python itself, without relying on an external utility.  See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/436220/5987

Answer (score 5):

This is an example for converting a CSV file in Python 3:

```
try:
    inputReader = csv.reader(open(argv[1], encoding='ISO-8859-1'), delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
except IOError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 7044: invalid continuation byte**

The above error is occuring due to encoding

Solution:-   Use “encoding='latin-1'”

Reference:- [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/search.html?q=encoding](https://UnicodeDecodeError:%20%27utf-8%27%20codec%20can%27t%20decode%20byte%200xed%20in%20position%207044:%20invalid%20continuation%20byte%20%20The%20above%20error%20is%20due%20to%20encoding%20%20%20Solution:-%20%20%20use%20%E2%80%9Cencoding=%27latin-1%27%E2%80%9D%20Reference:-%20https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/s%20earch.html?q=encoding)

Answer (score 3):

The encoding replaced with **encoding='ISO-8859-1'**

for line in open('u.item', encoding='ISO-8859-1'):

## print(line)

Answer (score 2):

**Sometimes** when using `open(filepath)` in which `filepath` actually is not a file would get the same error, so firstly make sure the file you're trying to open exists:

```
import os
assert os.path.isfile(filepath)
```

Comment: How would opening a file that doesn't exist generate a `UnicodeDecodeError`?  And in Python it's customary to use [the EAFP principle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/5987) over the LBYL that you're endorsing here.

Answer (score 2):

Open your file with [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), select "Encoding" or "Encodage" menu to identify or to convert from ANSI to UTF-8 or the [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) code page.

Comment: Notepad++ is [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) only. For example, it doesn't work on [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux).

Comment: What is *"Encodage"*? What language?

Comment: "Encodage" is "Encoding" if the menu is in French

Answer (score 1):

So that *the web-page is searched faster* for the google-request on a similar question (about error with UTF-8), I leave my solvation here for others.

I had problem with .csv file opening with that description:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 150: invalid continuation byte
```

I opened the file with NotePad & counted 150th position: that was a Cyrillic symbol.
I resaved that file with 'Save as..' command with Encoding 'UTF-8' & my program started to work.

Comment: Please note that questions and answers on SO must be in English only - even if the problem you encountered may bite mainly programmers using cyrillic alphabet.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, is it a real problem? Could you please give me a link/referense to the comunity rule on that issue?

Comment: This is considered a real problem - and is probably what caused your answer to get downvoted. Non-English content is not allowed on SO (see for example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content ), and the rule is really strictly respected. For questions in Russian, you have https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ , though ;)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille This applies to the English content, not problems with non-English symbols.  And this doesn't necessarily have to be about other languages, it could be a different UTF-8 character (for example, a checkmark).

Answer (score 1):

I keep coming across this error and often the solution is not resolved by `encoding='utf-8'` but in fact with `engine='python'` like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

file = "c:\\path\\to_my\\file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file, engine='python')
df
```

A link to the docs is here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this, if you are directly loading data from github or kaggle DF=pd.read_csv(file,encoding='ISO-8859-1')

Comment: Nobody said that the file in the question is a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this issue occurred because I modified the extension of an excel file (.xlsx) directly into a (.csv) file directly...

The solution was to open the file then save it as new (.csv) file (i.e. file -> save as -> select the (.csv) extension and save it. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was similar in that UTF-8 text was getting passed to the Python script.

In my case, it was from SQL using the sp_execute_external_script in the Machine Learning service for SQL Server. For whatever reason, VARCHAR data appears to get passed as UTF-8, whereas NVARCHAR data gets passed as UTF-16.

Since there's no way to specify the default encoding in Python, and no user-editable Python statement parsing the data, I had to use the SQL `CONVERT()` function in my SELECT query in the `@input_data` parameter.

So, while this query

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
OutputDataSet = InputDataSet
', 
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT id, text FROM the_error;'
WITH RESULT SETS (([id] int, [text] nvarchar(max)));
```

gives the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Using `CONVERT(type, data)` (`CAST(data AS type)` would also work)

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
OutputDataSet = InputDataSet
', 
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT id, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), text) FROM the_error;'
WITH RESULT SETS (([id] INT, [text] NVARCHAR(max)));
```

returns

```
id  text
1   Ç
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open the csv file and save as 'CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)'. You will find this in the list of Save As file options.

Once the file is save and closed then import the data

data = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')