# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: unexpected end of data

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, decode, tweetstream

I'm writing a code for stemming a tweet, but I'm having issues with encoding. When I tried to apply porter stemmer it shows error.Maybe i m not able to tokenize it properly.

My code is as follows...

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import scipy as sp
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


stemmer=nltk.stem.PorterStemmer()

p_test = pd.read_csv('TestSA.csv')
train = pd.read_csv('TrainSA.csv')

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

for i in range(len(train)-1):
    t = []
    #train.SentimentText[i] = " ".join(t)
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(train.SentimentText[i]):
        t.append(stemmer.stem(word))
    train.SentimentText[i] = ' '.join(t)
```

When I try to execute it returns the error:

---

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5aa856d0307f> in <module>()
     23     #train.SentimentText[i] = " ".join(t)
     24     for word in nltk.word_tokenize(train.SentimentText[i]):
---> 25         t.append(stemmer.stem(word))
     26     train.SentimentText[i] = ' '.join(t)
     27 

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/porter.pyc in stem(self, word)
    631     def stem(self, word):
    632         stem = self.stem_word(word.lower(), 0, len(word) - 1)
--> 633         return self._adjust_case(word, stem)
    634 
    635     ## --NLTK--

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/porter.pyc in _adjust_case(self, word, stem)
    602         for x in range(len(stem)):
    603             if lower[x] == stem[x]:
--> 604                 ret += word[x]
    605             else:
    606                 ret += stem[x]

/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc in decode(input, errors)
     14 
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 
     18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

anybody has any clue, wat is wrong with my code.I m stuck with this error.Any suggestions..?

Comment: Use `python3`, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c

Comment: To help you precisely, could you post the data set or a sample online. Without seeing the data, it's a shot in the dark to know what went wrong.

Comment: @alvis SentimentText contains the text of a tweet from twitter.

Comment: Knowing the genre of text doesn't help unless you can see and know what is the exact encoding of the data.

Comment: It seems very very likely that you're dealing with latin-1 encoding outside of ascii and by correctly encoding/decoding it as utf8, you might resolve the problem but still without seeing the data, it's just random guess as to what is happening =(

Comment: Also, do note that the "sin" of `sys.setdefaultencoding()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-we-need-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script

Answer (score 3):

I think the key line is 604, one frame above the place which raises the error:

```
--> 604                 ret += word[x]
```

Probably `ret` is an Unicode string and `word` is a byte string. And you cannot decode UTF-8 byte by byte, as that loop is trying to do.

The problem is that `read_csv` is returning bytes, and you are trying to do text processing on those bytes. That simply doesn't work, those bytes have to be decoded to Unicode first. I think you can use:

```
pandas.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')
```

If possible, use Python 3. Then trying to concatenate bytes and unicode will always raise an error, making it much easier to spot these problems.