# ImportError: No module named 'xlrd'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ubuntu, pycharm

I am currently using PyCharm with Python version 3.4.3 for this particular project.

This PyCharm previously had Python2.7, and I upgraded to 3.4.3.

I am trying to fetch data from an Excel file using Pandas.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("File.xls", "Sheet1")
print (df)
```

When I ran this code, I am getting this error.

```
ImportError: No module named 'xlrd'
```

I searched Stackoverflow and found some suggestions:
I tried with

```
pip install xlrd
```

But, when I did that, the message says

```
"Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in ./anaconda2/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `pip3 install xlrd`? PyCharm will already be offering to install it through the context sensitive help if you've selected the correct interpreter for the project.

Comment: I agree with jon you are probably pointing at the wrong interpreter when running pip. If you go to you pycharm settings - project interpreter you will see exactly where pycharm is executing.

Comment: open your anaconda prompt : conda install xlrd

Comment: what pip outputs clearly states you have it for python 2.7, and are trying to install for 2.7, but you are using 3.4.3 in pycharm.

Comment: I tried all above (pip3 install xlrd -> it says "The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install python3-pip, so I did. I went thru the process, and message said "python3-pip is already the newest version."   I checked the interpreter, and it is pointing to 3.4.3 in PyCharm. I typed conda install xlrd. It went thru the process. It says "All requested packages already installed. But it says xlrd   1.0.0  py27_0.

Comment: One way is, copy the packege `xlrd` from `./anaconda2/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to the `lib` directory PyCharm installation directory. This is because `pip` installs the packeges to `anaconda2` by default.

Comment: thanks @KingJava I have same problem and I used "pip install xlrd" and it worked with me

Comment: Shouldn't this be a transitive dependency for pandas and install when pandas is installed? I hit the same problem but this should've downloaded on its own right?

Answer (score 48):

I had the same problem. I went to the terminal (Using Linux), and typed

```
sudo pip3 install xlrd
```

Then I imported xlrd in python and used the same code:

```
df = pd.read_excel("File.xlsx", "Sheet1")
print (df)
```

It worked for me!!

Comment: It's not advisable to run `pip` with `sudo` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-and-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo)

Answer (score 9):

You have to download xlrd library because pandas require it.

In Pycharm I downloaded it in File -> Settings -> Project: [PROJECT NAME] -> Project Interpreter
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Running the `pip install xlrd` completed the installation, but that did not resolve the "no named module named xlrd" error.

Copying the xlrd folder to the same folder where the .py programs are stored, resolved this issue.

Comment: You are correct that you need to install xlrd.  Rather than moving/copying the folder, try importing xlrd (`import xlrd`) before reading your Excel file.

Comment: Yes...I did inport xlrd before trying to open the Excel file. But i kept getting the error...till i copied the folder

Comment: I ran into the same issue (windows10). tried pip install, pip3 install and conda install.  All failed. Moved the XLRD folder ('pip show XLRD') to the .py files folder and it works. Its not a great solution, but the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 9):

The problem seems to be because of multiple python versions in the system, where requirement might be satisfied for one and not for the other.

In this case the requirement is satisfied for python2 but not for python3, you need to specify that the download needs to be for python3.

In reference to the answers mentioned above, what worked for me is

```
python3 -m pip install xlrd
```

specifying python3 rather than pip3 worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was uninstalling `xlrd` using `pip uninstall xlrd`, and then installing it again using `pip install xlrd`.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the Bulb icon right next to the "import xlrd" & click on install package clrd , it will automatically install the package

Answer (score 2):

The answers listed to date did not work for me. Sadly, the only thing I had to do after running `pip install xlrd`, was to restart Visual Studio Code on my Windows 10. I know that it is a different OS than the OP, but hopefully, that helps someone else.

Oh yeah, and I know... restarting should have been my first step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a terminal under Bash or any other semi-advanced shell with tab-completion, try to write `pip` followed by `<tab>`. If I do it, I see written:

```
none@vacuum:~$ pip  
pip     pip3    pip3.5  pip3.6
```

As you can see, I can choose to run pip commands under `pip` only, but I can choose even newer versions of pip. To know what version is associated to the `pip` command (with nothing else) run as usual `pip` with the `--version` or `-V` flag. In my case, `pip -V` yields:

```
none@vacuum:~$ pip -V  
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

Besides this, if you are developing under PyCharm, you may press `Alt+Enter` when the cursor is under the module name which cannot be imported to open a context-sensitive floating menu that will allow you to install the module. (You can also manage the list of installed modules for a specific Python version in the settings menu of PyCharm, under the `Project Interpreter` sub-menu.)

Answer (score 0):

I have python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 in my linux Mint machine for some reasons.

My spyder uses python 3.5 and I had the same issue. What I have done is

- go to the folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
- Copy the folder `xlrd` (Note that to do this action you have right click and open as root)
- Now go to the `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` or `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` and paste the folder `xlrd` over there.

It worked for me!!!

This method does not change the default path so that, I can still continue with python 2.7 without any harm(something like `SageMath` which I use extensively)

Comment: I would caution that this method may not necessarily work for newer versions of Python, as 2.7 is not completely compatible with 3.x

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me using pycharm, I had installed it with pip, pip3 and anaconda and it still didn't work.
 I manually installed the package from 
`pycharm-> preferences -> project -> project interpreter -> +`
and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual environment use "pipenv install xlrd" instead of "pip install xlrd". That should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issues in Windows then try the steps below which works for me:

1. go to the location `%localappdata%`

   - `C:\Users\<YourSystem>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts`
2. Open cmd ternimal at this location
3. run `pip install xlrd`

Answer (score 0):

I copy the modules xlrd and xlrd-1.2.0.dist-info to the project file after `pip/conda install xlrd` , and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was using VS Code and in my case I have already installed xlrd but the import was not detecting. There were two reason for it:

1. I have not restarted my VS Code after pip install xlrd. So, just restart it.
2. I have two versions of Python installed and my VS Code interpreter was pointing to a previous version of Python which was not there in enviornment variable path of windows. So, I just changed the interpreter which the VS code was pointing. There is an interpreter version shown on bottom right corner of VS code and we can change it from there.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
pip install xlrd --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
 import pip
 package_name='xlrd'
 pip.main(['install', package_name])
```