# error No module named 'xlrd'. how to import excel with python and pandas properly? please close this

Tags: python, pandas

I realized that there may be something wrong in my local dev env just now.
I tried my code on colab.
it worked well.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('hurun-2018-top50.xlsx')
```

thank u all.

please close this session.

------- following is original description ---------

I am trying to import excel with python and pandas.
I already pip installed "xlrd" module.
I googled a lot and tried several different methods, none of them worked.
Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelFile
from pandas import ExcelWriter
df = pd.read_excel('hurun-2018-top50.xlsx', index_col=0)
df = pd.read_excel('hurun-2018-top50.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
df = pd.read_excel('hurun-2018-top50.xlsx')
```

Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like it's an env issue - are you sure `xlrd` and `pandas` are in the same environment?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244238/importerror-no-module-named-xlrd) might help.