# Vim Python ImportError No module named xlrd

Tags: python, vim

I have tried answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244238/importerror-no-module-named-xlrd)

But I still can't fix the same issue.
Here is my python code:

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel('airquality.xlsx')

print("Column headings:")
print(df.columns)

:!python 'readexcel.py'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readexcel.py", line 1, in <module>
    import xlrd
ImportError: No module named xlrd
shell returned 1
```

While I check the xlrd it shows it has been satisfied:

```
$python --version
Python 3.6.9
$ pip3 install xlrd
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.2.0)
```

while in terminal, it seems no issue:

```
    python
    Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)
    [GCC 8.3.0] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import xlrd
    >>>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I would advise against using `xlrd`. It's unmaintained, and is currently only recommended for handling the legacy .xls format. Also, are you not using virtual environments?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip3 install --upgrade xlrd
python3 readexcel.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by in .vimrc (using !python3 instead of !python):

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```