# How to Remove Impurities from Tweets Stored in a Text File?

Tags: python, text, tweets, twitter-streaming-api

I have a text file containing tweets. I want to extract only the User Name & Text from the file and want to remove all the other impurities like ASCII values and URLs. But when I'm executing my Python code, this error is coming:

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 5776245: character maps to "

Any solutions/Python code for doing this?

Comment: without seeing your code and the file it operates on .... Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors.

Comment: Please take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please edit your question and add your code after you read [ How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [decoding issue while parsing JSON \[python\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259515/decoding-issue-while-parsing-json-python)