# Failing parsing stackexchange XML files

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to parse the PostHistory.xml file from the [stack exchange dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). My code looks like that:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as eTree
with open("PostHistory.xml", 'r') as xml_file:
    xml_tree = eTree.parse(xml_file)
```

But I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode 
bytes in position 1959-1960: invalid continuation byte
```

I can read the text of the file like that:

```
with open("PostHistory.xml") as xml_file:
     a = xml_file.readline()
```

The file * command returns this description for the file:

```
PostHistory.xml: XML 1.0 document, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, 
with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

Also the first line of the file confirms the UTF-8 encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I tryed to add the parameter`encoding="utf-8-sig"` but I got the same error again.

The size of the file is 112 Gb.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: If the XML file is 112GB, you should use [`iterparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) instead. I also wouldn't open the file first; just use the path/filename in iterparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    with open(posts_path) as xml_file:  
        for line in xml_file:            
            try:                    
                xml_obj = eTree.fromstring(line)                    
            except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                # Dealing with corrupted encoded strings
                new_str = line.encode("latin-1", "ignore")
                xml_obj1 = eTree.fromstring(ww)
```

So when you get invalid characters you will encode them as "latin-1"

Answer (score 0):

The reality of the file's bytes may contradict the encoding specified in the XML declaration.  (Just setting the encoding in the XML declaration won't change the rest of the bytes in the file.)

You can try

```
open("PostHistory.xml", 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

but you may have to roll up your sleeves and repair the errant byte at `1959-1960` if it's a data corruption rather than an file-wide encoding problem.

**See also:**

- [Python 3 UnicodeDecodeError - How do I debug UnicodeDecodeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46180610/290085)
- [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19699367/290085)