# How do I rewind subprocess's output to capture output on failure?

Tags: python, io, subprocess

What's a generic way that I can capture output from `subprocess` **after** reading its output fails?

When I get a UnicodeDecodeError I want to see the original content to reproduce, but I'm not always able to run the command again to get the output.

If I avoid `text`/`universal_newlines`, then I can move the failure out of subprocess and more into my code. I can wrap the process's `stdout` in a `TextIOWrapper` to control the encoding but how do I see the content that failed to decode? seek isn't working.

So far I have this:

```
import io
import logging
import pprint
import shutil
import subprocess
import tempfile


def run_cmd(cmd):
    ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, text=False)

    data = None

    # Decode with a wrapper instead of text to force utf-8 instead of local
    # encoding (cp1252 on windows).
    output = io.TextIOWrapper(ps.stdout, encoding="utf-8")
    try:
        data = output.read()
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
            logging.warning("UnicodeDecodeError.")
            output.seek(0)
            shutil.copyfileobj(output, f)
            logging.error("UnicodeDecodeError. Wrote input to file: %s", f.name)
        raise

    return ps.wait(), data


pprint.pprint(run_cmd(["dir"]))  # My command actually contacts a server and sometimes fails.
```

But the log file is always empty. Is there a reason why `seek` isn't applicable in this case? [It should raise an error if unsupported](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seekable).

My specific error is: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 337: invalid start byte`, but I'm hoping for a way I can tackle this problem every time I encounter it.

*This question is about unicode errors from `subprocess` and not parsing a specific file like [Python 3 UnicodeDecodeError - How do I debug UnicodeDecodeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180610/python-3-unicodedecodeerror-how-do-i-debug-unicodedecodeerror)*

Comment: So the question isn't about unicode but it is tagged with `unicode`?

Comment: You've already received the output bytes (use `ps.communicate()`, BTW) and wrapping that stream in a different decoder is too late.  You have to control the process or its environment.  For example, `ps = subprocess.Popen('cmd /u /c dir', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, text=False, shell=False)` will receive the bytes from a Unicode shell, and the bytes will be encoded in UTF-16LE (Windows).  `out, err = ps.communicate()` and then `print(out.decode('utf-16le'))` will fetch and decode.

Comment: @ScottHunter: I made an edit to the italic section that maybe resolves your question. I want a general pattern to debug UnicodeDecodeError. Is that a correct use of the tag?

Comment: @idbrii that seems like a different question

Comment: Rephrased to be less about the unicode issue and more about io streams. Removed the unicode tag.