# How to convert AES encrypt output bytes to string and vise versa

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

I want to encrypt texts using PyCrypto AES and write the output ciphertext to a text file. As you know the `encrypt()` output returns bytes and so I have to decode it to unicode first for it to be accepted by `write()` method. My problem is both `str()` and `decode()` methods throw the same error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Here's part of the encrypted text I'm trying to decode to utf-8:

...`\xa5- \xd9\x14_\x02\x18\x96\xde\xbb\xad\xb57>\xe5i\x82H\x9b\xcc\x19y\x0f\x89\x0c~\x81\xb5(\xcc|6\x0b\x1c\xa3\x93E\x91d\xa4\x01\xb3\x98C\xb4,\x94@,\xb0\xb0\xd7\xe2\xf7\xf6U\x129B\xd6#u\x02\xc3\xe4l\xa3\x05V\x143\xe6\x85-\x88\x7f\x14\xc0\x1e\x1d\x19vQ\xbe\xc3\xda8\x06\xaf\xb9\xb7F\x91\xa6\xba&\xcb\xd7\xd0\x12\xed\xfd\xd3n\x06\xb6\x8fZ\xccpO\x05f\x`...

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte#19706723).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing to a binary file (something like)

```
binfile = open('bin.out', 'wb')
```

`wb` is the key, then you can just call `write`.

If you are writing to a text file, you'll need to use `base64` or something similar to encode in a format that can be included in text.  `base64` and `hex` are the common options.

To encode in base64 do something like

```
import base64
b64_string = str(base64.b64encode(bytes_obj),'utf-8')
```

Then use `b64decode` to get a string back

Comment: This is the correct method. Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o

Answer (score 0):

AES encryption can output all 1-byte hex numbers (0x00 to 0xFF), however UTF8 requires the last byte in each character  be  in the range 0x00 to 0x7F. This means there will be numerous AES characters that have no corresponding UTF-8 translation, which seems to be the error you're getting.

In fact, if you look closely at your sample text given, it is already in unicode-8. Look at the beginning of your example:

### \xa5- \xd9\x14_

This expression contains a unicode-8 hyphen, space, and underscore. The other raw bytes shown are those for which Python couldn't find a corresponding unicode-8 translation.
There is a hyphen, a

Comment: It's not called Unicode-8, but rather UTF-8. Also UTF-8 can use all values, but it has restrictions on what is valid. I corrected your text somewhat to reflect this. I apologize if I went too far and went beyond your intent