# Not capable to splitlines from a file (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, split

[image]

So I'm doing what I always do when I read the file:
code:

```
f= open(filename,'r')
t= f.read().splitlines()
print(t)
```

but I'm getting a UnicodeDecodeError  I don't know why.
the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 21, in <module>
    t= f.read().splitlines()
  File "/Users/jamilaldani/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 307: invalid start byte
```

Comment: what is input? can u put snippest

Comment: how do i add a snippet of the input? sorry for the dumb question

Comment: Copy and paste the file in , format as code

Comment: Don't post screenshots

Comment: the file is the following:

Comment: The file is too big it consists of elements from the periodic table, but the problem isn't from the file I'm trying to read because yesterday it worked fine but today I don't know why it stopped working.

Comment: use "file" command on your text file and see what encoding it reports

Comment: When I run the code this is what i get:

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 307: invalid start byte
Jamils-MacBook-Air:downloads jamilaldani$ python try.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 23, in <module>
    f=j.read()
  File "/Users/jamilaldani/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 307: invalid start byte

Answer (score 1):

As described in a few places on this site, and AndreaConte's comment this is likely to be a file encoded in a different encoding (ie not UTF-8)

This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706723/70131, 
as may this one if you're willing to lose some data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12468274/70131