# Pandas - read_csv encoding error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding

This is an issue that is quite common for me. So common that it seems I'm missing something (i.e., there has to be a better way). There are multiple posts on SO dedicated to this problem, but they seem to be workarounds rather than an actual solution. So, I have a CSV to read in:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename.csv)
```

I get the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
```

The *solution* is to use `cchardet` or `chardet` (`cchardet` is much much faster):

```
import cchardet as chardet
with open(filename.csv, 'rb') as f:
    result = chardet.detect(f.read())

df = pd.read_csv(filename.csv, encoding=result['encoding'])
```

This works but doesn't seem to be a long-term solution because even `cchardet` isn't guaranteed to find the correct encoding. Is there an option in `pd.read_csv` to *guess* the encoding? I'd rather it fail on a few characters then fail to read the entire file. With respect to frequency, nearly everytime I read in a CSV I have this problem and it makes `pandas` feel a little fragile. Tell me I'm missing something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate. I can workaround it. I'm wondering if there's a better way. I can't rely on the encoding to be stable, so I need 1) identify as I read the file which is slow OR 2) find a more flexible solution. I'm hoping there's a feature in pandas that I'm overlooking.

Comment: I think you'd be better off ensuring that the encoding is stable or explicit and just using that. Otherwise, you'll be stuck having to use tools like these.

Comment: I was afraid of that response, but thanks for the comment.