# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 14: invalid start byte

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to download one directory from my server on button click. The directory should be downloaded in zip format. I am using Django and Python. I tried this earlier  with the same code but it was on Python2 venv. The same code on Python3 venv gives **utf-8 codec can't decode byte** error. The  zip of the directory is created successfully but when i press the download button on my website it throws me above error.

```
@login_required
def logs_folder_index(request):
    user = request.user
    if not is_moderator(user):
        raise Http404("You are not allowed to see this page.")
    else:
        if os.path.exists('Experiments.zip'):
            os.remove('Experiments.zip')
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Experiments.zip','w',zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        path = settings.BASE_DIR + '/experiments/'
        zipdir(path,zipf)
        zipf.close()
        zip_file = open('Experiments.zip','r')
        response = HttpResponse(zip_file, 
                content_type='application/force-download')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{0}"'\
                                        .format(Experiments.zip)
        return response
```

Can someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: I don't think that it is a duplicate of that answer, because in this case the content is zip compressed, not badly encoded as in that case

Comment: Could there be any problem with the python versions?

Comment: what module does that `HttpResponse` come from?

Comment: Could you try to open the file in `rb` mode?

Comment: @WalterTross `django.http import HttpResponse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your read the file as a *text stream* (since the mode is `'r'`, and not `'rb'`). Since zips are typically not encoded in UTF-8 (or any text codec in general), it is likely to eventually reach a byte sequence that can not be decoded (or will be decoded non-sensical), you thus should read it as a *binary* file:

```
@login_required
def logs_folder_index(request):
    user = request.user
    if not is_moderator(user):
        raise Http404("You are not allowed to see this page.")
    elif os.path.exists('Experiments.zip'):
        os.remove('Experiments.zip')
    with zipfile.ZipFile('Experiments.zip','w',zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
        path = settings.BASE_DIR + '/experiments/'
        zipdir(path,zipf)
    with open('Experiments.zip','rb') as stream:
        response = HttpResponse(stream, content_type='application/force-download')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Experiments.zip"'
        return response
```