# Getting encoded csv from url into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests, urllib

I'm struggling to get the following `csv` from this site into `Pandas`.

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/773656/HMRC_spending_over_25000_for_December_2018.csv

I've tried a few things, but so far I can't make a workable `csv`. The ultimate aim is to be able to make it into a Pandas `dataframe`.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction and explain why the below doesn't work?

Using Python 3.7, Windows 10

```
import requests  
import urllib
import csv

csv_url = 'https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/773656/HMRC_spending_over_25000_for_December_2018.csv'

response = urllib.request.urlopen(csv_url)
cr = csv.reader(response)
for row in cr:
    print(row)
# csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

response = urllib.request.urlopen(csv_url)
response = response.read().decode()
cr = csv.reader(response)
for row in cr:
    print(row)
# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 28452: invalid start byte

response = requests.get(csv_url).text
cr = csv.reader(response)
for row in cr:
    print(row)
# malformed, prints individual characters
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using pandas >= `0.19.2`, you can input the `csv` url directly.:

```
import pandas as pd
url="https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/773656/HMRC_spending_over_25000_for_December_2018.csv"
c=pd.read_csv(url, encoding ='latin1') # otherwise you get a UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 12: invalid start byte
```

[Demo1](https://trinket.io/python3/16efc814ff)

---

Otherwise use [String.IO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html), i.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import StringIO
url="https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/773656/HMRC_spending_over_25000_for_December_2018.csv"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(StringIO(s.decode("latin1")))
```

[Demo2](https://trinket.io/python3/d2bc5cdcde)

Comment: the edit to encoding='latin1' solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: @lightalchemist, Seems to be an encoding problem of the [original csv](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/773656/HMRC_spending_over_25000_for_December_2018.csv) . It looks already like [this](https://i.imgur.com/3pjeknb.jpg): when I open it in open-office.

Comment: @PedroLobito I opened it in Microsoft Excel (on a Mac) and it shows the '-'. If you use 'cp1252' as the encoding, the mark will show up properly. Open-office probably was not able to figure out the proper encoding.

Answer (score 2):

This is an encoding issue as the file appears to use Windows-specific encoding.

```
df = pd.read_csv(url, encoding='cp1252')
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change encoding to cp1252

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url="https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/773656/HMRC_spending_over_25000_for_December_2018.csv"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode("cp1252")))
```

Comment: Can someone explain why cp1252 is necessary over utf-8 or latin1? How would I identify this myself in future?

Comment: @BenJones refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text. Hopefully it will help.