# How do I continue on error in loop condition in python?

Tags: python, loops, error-handling

I have python code that loops over a file. I'm getting a UTF-8 error `(invalid continuation byte)` when I read over the file. I just want my program to ignore that.

I've tried using a try except around the code inside, but that won't work since the error is in the condition of the for loop. I've also tried using a try except around the loop but then when it catches the error it doesn't start the loop again.

```py
with open(input_file_path, "r") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        # code irrelevant to question
```

What happens is it gives this error on `for line in input_file`:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 5: invalid continuation byte`
```

I want it to skip that line and move to the next one. Essentially, a try catch on the condition of my for loop.

Comment: Are you sure the file *should* be decoded as a UTF-8 stream? Adding the correct encoding the `open` function may be the correct answer.

Comment: @chepner Yes I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work? (edited to solution OP found)

```
with open(input_file_path, "r", encoding="utf8", errors="surrogateescape") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        try:
            yourcode
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: Yes I did and it doesn't work since te error is on the line `line in input_file`

Comment: then its not a line issue but prob a file issue? is the encoding correct?

Comment: a quick search came up with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: Yes I did see that.

Comment: If you change your answer to this: `with open(input_file_path, "r", encoding="utf8", errors="surrogateescape") as input_file:` I'll accept it. That worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this, when the UnicodeDecoceError is raised, the loop will continue with the next iteration.

```py
with open(input_file_path, "rb") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        try:
            line_i = line.decode(encoding='utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            continue
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work since the error is on the line `for line in input_file`

Comment: @SheshankS. Allright, maybe then read the file content as binary and convert at a later moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
with open(input_file_path, "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
```