# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 237: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python

I am trying to open a 14.6GB .lst file. Which encoding should I use? I always get the error, I am using Python3

```
  File "fb.py", line 58, in <module>
    passw=file.readline().strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 237: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Try with `encoding='latin1'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["for line in..." results in UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/for-line-in-results-in-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have utf-8 data. Try changing the encoding to `"ISO-8859-1"` in your `open()` statement.