# What is the default encoding for Python 2.7.8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

When I open a file with `codecs.open('f.txt', 'r', encoding=None)`, Python 2.7.8 chooses some default encoding.

Which is it? And where is this documented?

[Some experimentation](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tkCZYGYQ) has revealed that the default encoding is not `utf-8`, `ascii`, `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, or `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`.

**Edit (clarifying my motivation):** I want to know which encoding is chosen by Python 2.7.8 when I run a script like this:

```
f = codecs.open('f.txt', 'r', encoding=None) # or equivalently: f=open('f.txt')
for line in f:
    print len(line) # obviously SOME encoding has been chosen if I can print the number of characters
```

I'm not interested in other ways to guess the encoding of a file.

Comment: Python's default encoding is ASCII as noted here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#encodings

Comment: Then how can we explain this? http://i.imgur.com/Pw36l9B.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `codecs.open('f.txt','r',encoding=None)` returns byte strings instead of Unicode strings when the file is read.  It doesn't try to decode the file data with an encoding at all.  It is equivalent to `open('f.txt','r')`.  The length you receive is the number of individual bytes in the line as stored in the file with no translation.

A small example:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.open('f.txt','r',encoding=None).read()
'abc\n'
>>> codecs.open('f.txt','r',encoding='ascii').read() # Note Unicode string returned.
u'abc\r\n'
>>> open('f.txt','r').read()
'abc\n'
```

Comment: Actually i believe that, despite the python documentation, codecs.open('f.txt','r',encoding=None) is actually equivalent to open('f.txt','r') not open('f.txt','rb'). It only adds the 'b' if an encoding is specified. Have a look at the library code posted in my answer.

Comment: @StephenBriney, you're right.  I'll update.  The proof is also in the first `codecs.open` line.  It only returned `\n` instead of `\r\n` indicating text mode instead of binary.  I didn't notice that when I posted.

Comment: I think the documentation is very misleading where it says "Files are always opened in binary mode, even if no binary mode was specified."

Answer (score 3):

It basically wont do any transparent encoding / decoding at all it just opens the file and returns it.

Here is the code from the library: -

```
def open(filename, mode='rb', encoding=None, errors='strict', buffering=1):

    """ Open an encoded file using the given mode and return
        a wrapped version providing transparent encoding/decoding.
        Note: The wrapped version will only accept the object format
        defined by the codecs, i.e. Unicode objects for most builtin
        codecs. Output is also codec dependent and will usually be
        Unicode as well.
        Files are always opened in binary mode, even if no binary mode
        was specified. This is done to avoid data loss due to encodings
        using 8-bit values. The default file mode is 'rb' meaning to
        open the file in binary read mode.
        encoding specifies the encoding which is to be used for the
        file.
        errors may be given to define the error handling. It defaults
        to 'strict' which causes ValueErrors to be raised in case an
        encoding error occurs.
        buffering has the same meaning as for the builtin open() API.
        It defaults to line buffered.
        The returned wrapped file object provides an extra attribute
        .encoding which allows querying the used encoding. This
        attribute is only available if an encoding was specified as
        parameter.
    """
    if encoding is not None:
        if 'U' in mode:
            # No automatic conversion of '\n' is done on reading and writing
            mode = mode.strip().replace('U', '')
            if mode[:1] not in set('rwa'):
                mode = 'r' + mode
        if 'b' not in mode:
            # Force opening of the file in binary mode
            mode = mode + 'b'
    file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
    if encoding is None:
        return file
    info = lookup(encoding)
    srw = StreamReaderWriter(file, info.streamreader, info.streamwriter, errors)
    # Add attributes to simplify introspection
    srw.encoding = encoding
    return srw
```

As you can see if encoding is None it just returns the opened file.

Here is your file with each byte represented in decimal showing its corresponding ascii character:

```
46  .
46  .

46  .
32  'space'

48  0
45  -

49  1
10  'line feed'

10  'line feed'
91  [

69  E
118 v

101 e
110 n

116 t
32  'space'

34  "
72  H

97  a
114 r

118 v
97  a

114 r
100 d

32  'space'
67  C

117 u
112 p

32  'space'
51  3

48  0
180 'this is not ascii'

34  "
93  ]

10  'line feed'
46  .

46  .
46  .
```

The issue you are having when opening it in ascii is the byte with the decimal value 180. Ascii can only go up to 127. So this got me thinking this must be some kind of extended ascii where 128 - 255 are used for extra symbols. After a good read of the wikipedia article about ascii (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) it mentioned a popular extension to ascii called windows-1252. In windows-1252 the decimal value 180 maps to the acute accent character (´). Then i decided to google the string in your file to see what it actually related to. And this is when i found "Harvard Cup 30´" http://www.365chess.com/tournaments/Harvard_Cup_30%C2%B4_1989/21650

So in summery the correct encoding is probably windows-1252. Here is my test program: -

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('f.txt', 'r', encoding='windows-1252') as f:
    print f.read()
```

outputs

```
... 0-1

[Event "Harvard Cup 30´"]
...
```

Comment: Then what encoding is chosen when I iterate over the lines in the returned file? e.g. http://i.imgur.com/Pw36l9B.png

Comment: What do you get if you do f = open('f.txt', 'r')      print f.encodeing

Comment: Have you tried chardet yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323770/character-detection-in-a-text-file-in-python-using-the-universal-encoding-detect

Comment: Not yet -- it seems useful but I'm just trying to reproduce the behavior of `open('f.txt' ,'r'); for line in f: pass`

Comment: `print(open('test.txt', 'r').encoding)` prints `None`

Comment: can you post the file somewhere?

Comment: Check the pastebin link in my question -- I include a hex dump of the file and the result of running a few python commands. Or you can download here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/907284/questionably_encoded.txt . The problem is caused by character U+00B4.

Comment: I have got you file to open with a specified encoding now. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just wondering why you didn't award me the correct answer? I already told you that opening the file with encoding = none is equivalent to simply opening the file with no transcoding and I have also actually solved your problem by working out that your file is encoded in windows-1252?